# Почему регулярное выражение [a-zA-Z] не находит Б?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

```
from re import compile, UNICODE

text = input('Enter only letters: ')

result = bool(compile(r'[a-zA-Z]', flags=UNICODE).search(text))
print(result)
```

Почему не работает с юникодом, например я ввожу Б получаю False.

Comment: Может потому что `Б` не принадлежит диапазону: `[a-zA-Z]` ? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

В диапазон [a-zA-Z] не входит, Вы можете явно указать, что нужно сопоставлять с кириллицей r'[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]' или так r'\w' во втором случае помимо букв в сопоставление будут включены символы 0123456789_ . Флаг UNICODE в Python3 ставится по дефолту, так что его прописывать не обязательно.

```
bool(compile(r'[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]').search(text)) #1 вариант. За ёЁ спасибо jfs и gil9red 
bool(compile(r'\w').search(text)) #2 вариант
```

Comment: 1- `[а-я]` не работает: попробуйте [`text='ё'`](https://ideone.com/9pmhHu). 2- `flags=UNICODE` на Питоне 3 излишне приводить.

Comment: 1) Добавить ё: `[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]`

Comment: @gil9red: это не поможет для `'ё'` случая (U+435 U+308)

Comment: @jfs, это когда символ на самом деле состоит из двух? Как тогда быть?

Comment: @gil9red: от конкретной задачи зависит (лучшее — враг хорошего). Можно игнорировать, можно нормализовать (NFC), можно как последовательность рассматривать (grapheme cluster) `[..]|ab`.

Answer (score 0):

что означает `[a-zA-Z]`? То что в этот диапазон входят все символы от `a` до `z` и от `A` до `Z`. Буква `Б` сюда не входит. Для включения так же русских символов необходимо сделать маску `[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]`.

Дело в том что каждому символу соответствует свой номер, диапазон a-z означает что все символы номер которых от номера `a` до номера `z`, эти символы имеют последовательную нумерацию. Отдельно указывается `A-Z` так как там нумерация уже идёт в другом блоке, отдельно от `a-z`, аналогично и для `а-я`, `А-Я`, `ёЁ`.
Тире соответствует диапазону от `a` до `z`.